# ADD Listener to image in Sencha Architect3

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I have image in a panel .I want to add a tap listener to image using sencha architect. 
 I need when user tap on image get that position . How can i add this? Any one can help me plz..

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this in the Architect docs:

[Events and Controllers: Adding Interactivity](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/3/#!/guide/interactivity)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.